# Accessing internet from device connected to AP

Tags: networking, iptables, embedded, nat

I have two interfaces `uap0` and `eth0` in my embedded Linux device. `uap0` acts as an access point for other devices to connect to Linux Device. `eth0` interface is connected to my router. And my router is connected to internet.

Details about the interfaces:

- `uap0` - 172.24.100.1/24

  DHCP range for devices connecting to AP: 172.24.100.50 - 172.24.100.100
- `eth0` - 192.168.1.26/24

  Router's IP (which is gateway): 192.168.1.253

  ```
  route add default gw 192.68.1.253
  ```

  since this is the router's IP. I tried with 172.24.100.1 as well. But it also didn't work.

I have allowed IPv4 forwarding in `sysctl.conf` file. I have also added following entries to the iptables:

```shell
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o uap0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i uap0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Ping results:

- `ping 172.24.100.50 -I uap0` ---> Success (.50 is one of the devices connected to AP)
- `ping 8.8.8.8 -I uap0` ---> Failure
- `ping 192.168.1.26 -I uap0` ---> Failure
- `ping 172.24.100.1 -I eth0` ---> Failure

**Whenever I have a device connected to AP, there is no internet access in the device. Almost every solution I have gone through in the web recommends to add entries to the iptables which I have already done.**

I had implemented AP+STA mode in Raspberry Pi previously. I had to configure dnsmasq and hostapd in RPi. But since this is a minimal linux system, I don't have the dnsmasq preinstalled. Also, package managers don't work as expected.

Network diagram as per my current setup:
[image: Netowrk diagram.]

The green part is the linux device.

Output of iptables-save:
[image: iptables-save]

Output of sysctl:

[image]

Comment: Please add the output of `iptables-save` and `nft list ruleset` to your question. The fact that you added the rules does not necessarily mean that they are being used (especially when you add them by using `-A`).

Comment: @TomYan nft is not available in this device. So, I just added the output of iptables-save.

Comment: So have you actually tried to ping some "remote" *IP* (e.g. `8.8.8.8` and `192.168.1.253`) from a WiFi client? Was that what you mean by `ping 8.8.8.8 -I uap0`? You are iptables are "fine" (as in, your don't even need any rules since your `FORWARD`'s policy is `ACCEPT`.) Double check `sysctl -a | grep forward`, maybe.

Comment: @TomYan I tried pinging 8.8.8.8 with my uap0 interface. uap0 is the AP interface I created in my Linux device. I have shown this inteface in the figure above. You may check in the question. Also, I have added output of sysctl.

Comment: What I mean is, why `pinging 8.8.8.8 with my uap0 interface` (instead of testing from an actual client)? I don't know much about `-I` in ping but AFAIK, it doesn't simulate the same thing as pinging from an actual client connected to thr AP.

Comment: -I lets me choose the interface to ping from. Pinging from the client also shows no connectivity to the internet. I thought uap0 should ping the server if it is connected to it.

Comment: See if `tcpdump -eni any icmp` with pinging some remote host from an actual client give you insight.

Comment: @TomYan tcpdump is not available in this device unfortunately.